# Is it allowed to ask if a contributor is for hire as a consultant?

Tags: support

I would like to ask one of your contributors if they are for hire as a consultant, is that allowed?

If so, how should I contact them? Should I post my interest in their services under their answer?

I don't want to break any rules and could not find this subject in a search.

Thanks in advance for the correct protocol in this regard.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Posters that would welcome such an offer likely:

- are signed up with their real name, so you could search them on the web
- leave contact details in their profile pages

For others, it should be assumed that they wish to remain anonymous.

Regardless, asking them in a comment to one of their contributions, whether they would agree to a private exchange is not forbidden, I think.

Comment: Thank you @tobalt

Answer (score 3):

I'll offer an alternative.
On my profile I include my contact email address as is allowed by the system.
If people wish to contact me they can, and a number of people have done so over the years.  While this has the disadvantage of people 'arriving on your logical doorstep' with a range of queries, that is also an advantage.

You could place an email address on your profile and then invite the user to contact you privately using the profile address. Such a request could be for a range of reasons and while I'm sure some would frown on even this approach, it seems to me (fwiw) that it is an acceptable use of the system.

If desired you can use one-purpose email addresses (eg from gmail) and redirect all messages to a main account. I use a version of this facility when giving my email address to potential spammers.

I'm available for consulting purposes if the subject is suitably interesting :-). (That may be quite a high bar to meet in many cases.)

Comment: Thank you for the answer. I will reach out to you. Have a great weekend.

Comment: I am on another project for the time being. When I return to this particular job, I'll reach out if I still require assistance.  Thanks again.

Comment: @tayglo  It's always interesting to hear from people. Depending on what your requirement is many others on this site may be suitable candidates. Asking a related question my also show you who has good related ideas. (Please let me know if you do so :-) )